# HTML page parsing

Tags: java, html, parsing

I need to parse a lot of HTML pages (and write parsed data into a database) with various formats on a daily basis, do you know if there is a visual tool that I can use? I would like to point at what need to extract, save it to some kind of config, and execute it in prod. 
I am trying to avoid dipping my head into Jsoup and stuff like that.

Thanks

Comment: Would any tools like a rich text editor help

Comment: Vague question, what do you have now? How is it going to save? and execute? How do you transform the HTML into the data you're going to store?

Comment: The transformation should be taken care by the tool. I would provide locations on the page and mappings to db tables

Comment: Think of it as a training for a web fetcher. I would like to "train" it instead of coding all the parsing

Comment: Still not enough info, where is the list of pages? What part is UI based, giving up...

Comment: You know when you have to create code to parse html elements, to loop through nodes until you hit the right node. So, I don't want to do all of that. I want to load desired page into some tool and point to what elements I want to extract from the page. The tool should figure out how to traverse html doc to get my data.

Comment: I have never heard of such a tool. HTML is designed for rendering documents and graphics. It is not easy for machine to understand. That's why XML and Semantic web exists. Without coding the logic into the parser, you can never get the machine to extract the information you need. What you are looking for is probably an AI. As far as I know, it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a combination of [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) and [Pentaho Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/):

- http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-tidy-to-clean-webpages-with.html